# The scripting or operator

Tags: javascript, symbols

In fx Javascript you got the "OR" operator as ∥ but that in math as far as i know is "x ∥ y means x is parallel to y."

So if had an mathematical issue where i could ether minus or plus to get the result and then show its ether one or the other

24 +- 4 = 16∥28
something like that

I wanna find out is there an mathematical "or" operator and does it even make sense to write?

i read trough [**THIS**](http://www.tmrfindia.org/sutra/v2i17.pdf) list dosn't seem to exist so you might know

Comment: or is `||`, not this unicode symbol you used

Comment: ty for the fast answer - so its the same in math?

Comment: Are you aware that JavaScript is a computer language and not a mathematical notation? JavaScript operators mean what the JavaScript authors decide, and it's often influenced by what's easily available in a regular computer keyboard. It's like asking whether jQuery's `$` symbol means US dollars or Mexican pesos...

Comment: im aware - and i just seeked the || operator in math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write it out. So the question whether this be true: `24 +- 2 = x` is:

```
22 == x || 26 == x
```

The `||` is the only mathematical **arithmetical or** we got.
There also exists `|`, which is the logical or, but that is probably not what you want for this case.

Comment: makes sense same in scripting

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking, but if you want to know the mathematical notation for these symbols, they're the *conjunction* operator ∧ (**and**), the *disjunction* operator ∨ (**or**) and the *negation* operator ¬ (**not**).